# How to transpose this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
columns= ['1972 [YR1972]',
 '1973 [YR1973]',
 '2007 [YR2007]',
 'Country Name',
 'Series Code']

index = np.arange(10) # array of numbers for the number of samples
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
```

There are basically some 100.000 rows, since there are roughly 220 countries and 1000 Series Codes.

Unfortunately, this structure is not really to my liking- I would like to transpose the whole thing so that the I have the Series Codes as Columns, a year column and a country column - while the value is in the rows. I figured that I should use the pivot function, but the result is not what I expected.
Could someone guide me how to achieve this with pandas?

The result should look like this:

```
columns= ['Year', 'Country', 'SeriesCode1', 'SeriesCodeN']

index = np.arange(6) # array of numbers for the number of samples
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, index = index)
df['Year'] = ['1972 [YR1972]', '1973 [YR1973]', '2007 [YR2007]']*2
df['Country'] = ["Afghanistan"] *3 + [ "Zimbabwe"]*3
```

Comment: Could you show what's your desired output? Like index, columns, ...

Comment: @Anzel I have added an example, did it help?

Comment: that helps understand what your desired output look like. However still uncertain what do you want to do with the data, ie. sum? count? it would be better if you have a set of reproducible data sample + desired output (from sample).

Comment: @Anzel There is no need for a sum or aggregration, as the number of cells should be the same - just rows turned to columns and vice versa.
I will try to prepare a better example when I arrive at home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [pd.melt()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt) to do this.

All you should need is:
`pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Country Name', 'Series Code'], var_name='Year', value_name='your_values')`
and it will flatten the data out for you.